# Lots's of ` kernel: [ ] output chain dropped: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 ` in `/var/log/messages`

Tags: ubuntu, debian, iptables, kernel, nftables

I already disble `ipv6` in `mypc` debian 10  system,firewall is `nftable`.
When I check `/var/log/messages`,lots of `kernel: [ ] output chain dropped` as below:

```
Jul 13 11:03:14 mypc kernel: [ 8206.745775] output chain dropped: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:cad3:ffff:fe6e:e23b DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=248793 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0 UID=0 GID=0
Jul 13 11:03:18 mypc kernel: [ 8210.745624] output chain dropped: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:cad3:ffff:fe6e:e23b DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=248793 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0 UID=0 GID=0
Jul 13 11:03:22 mypc kernel: [ 8214.745440] output chain dropped: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:cad3:ffff:fe6e:e23b DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=248793 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0 UID=0 GID=0
Jul 13 11:03:26 mypc kernel: [ 8218.745303] output chain dropped: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:cad3:ffff:fe6e:e23b DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=248793 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0 UID=0 GID=0
Jul 13 11:03:30 mypc kernel: [ 8222.745452] output chain dropped: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:cad3:ffff:fe6e:e23b DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=248793 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0 UID=0 GID=0
```

My network didn't support ipv6,and I already disable ipv6 in debian.
What's the problem?

Comment: These messages indicate you blocked IPv6 in your firewall, not disabled it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton,I disable ipv6,by reference of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402217/disabling-ipv6-on-mint-and-debian

Comment: @kittygirl the link you provide should indeed have disabled IPv6, but your log shows that it's not disabled anyway. Probably one of your other system settings re-enabled it. You can verify with `/sbin/sysctl net.ipv6.conf.enp0s31f6.disable_ipv6` . 0 means *not* disabled

Comment: @A.B,Should I add `net.ipv6.conf.enp0s31f6.disable_ipv6 = 1`?I didn't find this in reference post.

Comment: My comment wasn't to solve anything, it was to verify where you're at. it should be typed exactly as I wrote it, and you should provide the result. I assume then that the result was `net.ipv6.conf.enp0s31f6.disable_ipv6 = 1` meaning that you *didn't* disable IPv6 even if you took steps to disable it (which failed at disabling it somehow) and it explains the logs.